# Can't execute PHP via browser on Centos 8

Tags: centos, php, apache-2.4

I already installed Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.4 on Centos 8, which is running on Google Cloud Platform.

Apache:

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf, php74-php-fpm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-07-29 07:55:37 UTC; 41min ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
 Main PID: 20366 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 19; Idle/Busy workers 100/0;Requests/sec: 0.0076; Bytes served/sec:  63 B/sec"
    Tasks: 278 (limit: 9312)
   Memory: 35.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─20366 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─20368 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─20369 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─20370 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─20371 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─20583 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Jul 29 07:55:37 test-app-devel1 systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 29 07:55:37 test-app-devel1 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 29 07:55:37 test-app-devel1 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 29 07:55:37 test-app-devel1 httpd[20366]: Server configured, listening on: port 443, port 80
```

PHP:

```
php --version
PHP 7.4.8 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2020 08:57:23) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Running PHP scripts directly using `php` command works fine. The problem is cannot execute PHP file via browser. I got this 503 error:

> Service Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your
> request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try
> again later.

There are a few current entries from the apache log:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [29/Jul/2020:08:15:17 +0000] "GET /test.txt HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [29/Jul/2020:08:15:19 +0000] "GET /test.txt HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [29/Jul/2020:08:15:32 +0000] "GET /ASF20thAnniversary.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 72242 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [29/Jul/2020:08:15:41 +0000] "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 503 299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [29/Jul/2020:08:16:01 +0000] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
```

Both txt and jpg files are loaded properly. But not the php file.
How to fix this?

Comment: Can you show us your PHP-FPM configuration?

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: @RaffaelLuthiger Here: https://gist.github.com/anta40/c7aa48860ea9a04716d6e0727fc28183

Comment: @MichaelHampton Perhaps this is the culprit? `[Mon Aug 03 03:17:36.765589 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 45406:tid 140621893318400] [client 182.253.0.226:57511] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
[Mon Aug 03 03:17:39.528903 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 45406:tid 140621859747584] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /var/opt/remi/php74/run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed`

Comment: Yes, that would do it. Is php-fpm running?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes. `status php-fpm.service` says "Active (running)"

Comment: @anta40 That's the general config. I need the config for this specific pool. From your error message above it seems as if you want to connect with the domain/file socket to your pool. i could imagine that your pool only provides a network socket.